# How to upgrade (install) windows 10 with minimum disk space?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation

I have a windows 10 Mini pc where I do not have enough disk space on the one internal disk to upgrade.  I have tried what I can think of to free up space.

Would like know how I can do  the upgrade with minimum free disk space?
I am primary thinking of using an USB for temporary files and backups (created by installer).  Or perhaps having some stuff going to the USB.

Currently it wants to do a feature upgrade, which is perhaps more like an installation.   Will do a fresh install if necessary, but prefer to keep as much as possible of settings.

Comment: No matter what method you use, the installation of a feature update, requires significant amount of free space.  This is because Windows is installed, then your profile is moved to that new installation, and your existing installation is moved to Windows.old.  You would have to delete the existing partition to avoid that process.

Comment: If you go to the [Windows 10 Update Assistant](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/81031-update-latest-version-windows-10-using-update-assistant.html), this might help you too.

Comment: @user1574981 In what way?  Think it does a more direct upgrde, which should require MORE disk space.